# Find indefinite integral $\int \frac{e^x(x^4+2)}{(1+x^2)^{5/2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Although I looked up the answer on integral calculator com but I still have little to no idea as to how one would proceed to solve this integral.
Integrate $\dfrac{e^x(x^4+2)}{(1+x^2)^{5/2}}$ wrt $x.$ I initially tried to convert it to the form $e^x\cdot(f(x)+f'(x)).$ However, I wasn't successful in spite of struggling for more than half an hour :(

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You've been here for over a year. Please use MathJax.

Comment: @Ak19 I dont know how to use math jax.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @adityagupta Have you tried a rationalizing substitution?

Comment: @OliverJones whats a rationalising sub? like multiply and divide by (1+x^2)^(1/2)?

Answer (score 5):

Hint

$$\dfrac{e^x\cdot f(x)}{dx}=?$$

So, it is sufficient to find $f(x)$ such that $$f(x)+f'(x)=\dfrac{x^4+2}{(1+x^2)^{5/2}}$$

As the degree of the denominator is $(5/2)\cdot2$

We can safely start with $$f(x)=\dfrac{a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4}{(1+x^2)^{5/2-1}}$$

Comment: could you kindly explain why we need to go till $a_4 x^4$ in the numerator?

Comment: @Riz222, Observe that the highest of the numerator is $4$

Answer (score 5):

Note

$$\left[\frac x{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}\right]’
=\frac {1-2x^2}{(1+x^2)^{5/2}}
=\frac {x^4+2}{(1+x^2)^{5/2}}-\frac1{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}$$

Then, integrate by parts

$$\int \frac{e^x(x^4+2)}{(1+x^2)^{5/2}}dx
= \int e^x d\left[\frac x{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}\right]
+\int \frac{e^x}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}dx$$
$$=\frac {e^xx}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}
+\int \left[ -\frac{xe^x}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}
+\frac{e^x}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}\right]dx$$
$$=\frac {e^x x}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}
+\frac{e^x}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}+C
$$

Comment: Nice way but you lost an $x$ during your partial integration. Besides this, it might be helpful to mention that in the last step you use $\left(\frac{1}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{\frac 12}}\right)' = -\frac{x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{\frac 32}}$ and hence, you use $(e^xu(x))' = e^x(u(x)+u'(x))$ with $u(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{\frac 12}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the note. But no sure about where to find the lost $x$.

Comment: I added the lost $x$ in my edit. :-)

Comment: No wonder, thanks