# Find $\int\left[\frac{\log x-1}{1+(\log x)^2}\right]\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

> $$
> \int\left[\frac{\log x-1}{1+(\log x)^2}\right]\mathrm{d}x
> $$

Set $t=\log x\implies\mathrm{d}t=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}x$
$$
\int\frac{\log x-1}{1+(\log x)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int\frac{t-1}{t^2+1}\mathrm{e}^t\,\mathrm{d}t\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac1{t^2+1}=\frac{-2t}{(t^2+1)^2}
$$

I think I am stuck, so is it the right substitution to obtain the solution or is there a better way to solve the given integral ?

My reference gives the solution $\dfrac{x}{1+(\log x)^2}$

**Note:** My reference is not that reliable, possible typo can be expected either in the question or in the solution.

Comment: The derivative of $\frac{x}{1+(\log x)^2}$ is $\left(\frac{\log x -1}{1+(\log x)^2}\right)^2$. So is there a square over the integrand?

Comment: @Ak19 my reference can be wrong, its not that reliable.

Comment: I don think that the indefinite integral had a closed form, indeed Wolfram Mathematica gives the result as a complicated expression of special functions

Comment: @Ak19 if there is a square then the solution is correct ?

Comment: @ss1729 Yeah! Then it'd be easy to solve and the solution is correct.

Comment: @Ak19 actually I see the whole integrand in a bracket, so it can be a typo, that the book missed the square part ?

Comment: @ss1729 So, yeah! Most probably..

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493729/find-indefinite-integral-int-fracexx421x25-2dx/3493746#3493746

Comment: @Ak19 Thanks man, in that case its a piece of cake, in the form $\int e^t(g(t)+g'(t))dt=e^t.g(t)+c$

Comment: You're most welcome! @ss1729

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's follow @Ak19's suggestion that we're trying to integrate $\frac{(t-1)^2}{(t^2+1)^2}e^t$ instead. A sensible Ansatz is $\frac{f(t)}{t^2+1}e^t$. So$$\frac{(t-1)^2}{(t^2+1)^2}e^t=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{f(t)e^t}{t^2+1}=\frac{f(t)e^t}{t^2+1}\left(\frac{f^\prime(t)}{f(t)}-\frac{2t}{t^2+1}+1\right),$$which simplifies to$$f^\prime(t)+\frac{(t-1)^2}{t^2+1}f(t)=\frac{(t-1)^2}{t^2+1}.$$Obviously, $f=1$ is a solution, which recovers the sought antiderivative. For more general ones, we of course add $+C$.

If this argument smacks of one we'd only make if we already know the answer, note that an Ansatz $g(t)e^t$ would work if$$g^\prime+g=\frac{(t-1)^2}{(t^2+1)^2}=\frac{1}{t^2+1}-\frac{2t}{(t^2+1)^2},$$so we can take $g=\frac{1}{t^2+1}$.