# $f(x)$ such that $f(x)+f'(x)=\frac{1+3x+x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, functions, fractions

I started with $\displaystyle f(x)=(A+Bx)\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

So, $f(x)+f'(x)=\dfrac{(A+B)+(A+B)x+(2B+A)x^2+Bx^3}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\dfrac{1+3x+x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Equating the coefficients of like powers of $x$, $B=0$. But then there are two different values of $A$, which is impossible. Does it mean there exists no such $f(x)$? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You have assumed $f(x)=(A+Bx)\sqrt{1+x^2}$ and found no function of **this form** exists .

Comment: Can you suggest any other forms?

Answer (score 3):

What you have here is a first-order differential equation. Letting $y=f(x)$, your equation is
$$y'+y=\frac{1+3x+x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=:g(x)$$
There is quite a complete theory to deal with such differential equations. Try multiplying both sides by $e^x$ to find that
$$e^x y'+e^xy=e^xg(x)$$
How can you simplify the left-hand side (think of the product rule)?

Comment: Robert Z did that already 5 minutes before you.

Answer (score 2):

The given ODE is linear and after multiplying by $e^x$ we find that
$$D(e^xf(x))=e^x(f(x)+f'(x))=\frac{(1+3x+x^2)e^x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
which implies that
$$f(x)=f(0)+e^{-x}\int_0^x\frac{(1+3t+t^2)e^t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt.$$
I think that the integral has no closed form.
Where does this ODE come from?

Comment: Should've cleared it in the question :D. Actually, this didn't come from any particular formula or problem (no ODE tag). After seeing [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3493746/) answer, I was under the impression that any *algebraic* expression could be expressed in $f(x)+f'(x)$ form. Is there a particular form that can always be put in $f(x)+f'(x)$ form? (Like- all rational functions can be integrated).

Comment: @Riz222 I don't know whether there is such particular form. Anyway $f$ exists also in this case but it can't be expressed in a closed form by using  standard functions.